# Full width drop down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have gone online and found a good looking drop down menu and have been trying to edit the code so the drop down menu is 100% of the width of the screen and then inside that ill have a wrap which will hold my links at a width of 960px. But im unable to get the drop down to be 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/jWSPz/

I think the problem is in here somewhere...

```
 ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
  }
```

That is the drop down I've been trying to edit.
I want it similar to this drop down

http://au.beatsbydre.com/

Comment: In you jsfiddle, just take the left and right padding out of your body and it stretches to 100%

Comment: Is this the code after you modified it? You've got `width: 150px` in there, which immediately jumps out as a possible cause of your problem. Also, this CSS is for a `ul` inside an `li` inside a `ul`... It's very possible that the outer `ul` or the `li` that contains this `ul` is limiting your width.

Comment: The reason is, that the beatsbydre has a div that drops down that loads content into a fullsize div, you have individual divs that then have content inside of them. You will need to go about achieving this another way. Which is not to difficult if your not a programmer, you can go to codecanyon and find hundreds of these for cheap. Sorry i cant be of any other help though, this takes lots of Javascripting or jquery programming to do.

Comment: @KyleG. I can change the width to certain pixel sizes and it changes but i cant change it to 100% http://jsfiddle.net/jWSPz/7/

Comment: @Cam could I possibly make the divs after the entire ul and still have the li:hover 'divName' css there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get it the width of the menu witch i think is what you want,

## [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jWSPz/4/)

i added the following (so simple) code

removed

```
ul li{
   position:relative;
}
```

and added to

```
ul{
   position:relative;
}
```

if you want it the full width of the screen just do this

REMOVE

```
ul li{
   position:relative;
}
```

ADD

```
ul li .dropDown{
     top: 75px;
}
```

## [Working Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jWSPz/9/)

Hope This Helps,

Good Luck :)

Comment: The sample I see has the info directly under the menu that was selected, configure that and you got the solution, kudos, drebeats website does it differently using code, but who cares the outcome is the objective.

Comment: @Cam Yeah I looked at the drebeats code but it was a little confusing to me and thought I could just edit the drop down I had already found rather than completely code a new one.

Comment: Please Accept if this is the best answer, would appreciate it thanks :)

Comment: @Connor woops, forogt. Done now :)

Comment: hi @iConnor, is it able to work like this (http://jsfiddle.net/bmfcd3zt/8/) but each menu have the drowndown menu like yours?